# Print the output of vim-scripts function in current line

Tags: vimscript

Say I want to print the output of `strftime("%D")` in the current line, or to print the `return` of any user-defined function for that matter. What's the  standard (one step?) way to do it?

I currently do this: `:let @a=strftime("%D")`, then `"ap` (two steps, but can be combined with mapping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From command-line mode, use `:put` in combination with with the expression register `"=` (inserts *after* the **current line**):

```
:put =strftime('%d')<CR>
```

---

Or, in Insert mode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> (inserts *before* the **cursor position**, as if typed with no abbreviations or mappings):

```
<C-r>=strftime('%d')<CR>
```

---

Or, in Normal mode, use <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (inserts *after* the **cursor position**):

```
"=strftime('%d')<CR>p
```

---

Relevant help:

```
:h quote=
:h :put
:h i_CTRL-R
:h quote
:h p
```

Comment: or in insert mode: `<c-r>=strftime('%d')`

Comment: Or normal mode `"=strftime('%d')<cr>p`

Comment: @Jake for some reason it requires \ before the two ". I like Christian's solution better cause it inputs the date in the current line after cursor.

Comment: @MahbubAlam all the ways suggested are equally valid depending on the context. I just mirrored what you said your current process was.

Comment: @JakeGrossman Does " in command line have a special meaning? Why doesn't it work? I was looking for printing in the current line.

Comment: @MahbubAlam they can be used to start comments; it's odd that in this case single-quotes are required, as in most other places you could use double-quotes with no issue